# Onclick event not firing for img elements in google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Since upgrading to Chrome 50.0.2661.87 m from version 49 earlier today my img elements on my google maps page are not firing their onclick events.  These img's are added to the page dynamically with javascript using the google maps api controls array.  I have been able to reproduce the problem in a simple google maps implementation shown [here](http://diamondmaps.com/imgClickIssue.html).  In IE and Firefox the chat button on this page fires and displays the alert.  But in Chrome 50 it only fires sometimes.  I can reproduce the problem on a coworker's computer.  It seems to work the first time you hit the page but if you reload it doesn't work.  When you click the "live chat" button it should display an alert.  Also, if I place a span and div element on the map as siblings to the img element using the same technique their onclick events fire just fine.

Below is the code for the page referenced above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization,geometry"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize()
        {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "http://diamondmaps.com/img/btnchat.png";
            img.onclick = function ()
            {
                alert('click');
            };
            container.style.padding = '5px';
            container.appendChild(img);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(container);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prompted by the answer from Ad.Infinitum I have been experimenting with different timing and order of events.  I was able to get a temporary solution working in which I don't subscribe to the onclick event until after the image loads.  This is ugly and I don't understand why it would work but I haven't been able to get it to fail since making this change.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'd want your event handlers to be attached before you set img.src.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onclick = function () {
  alert('click');
};
img.src = "http://diamondmaps.com/img/btnchat.png";
```

Having said that, there's incoming reports that Chrome 50 breaks img.onload.

> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/p51Lk7vnP2o

I'm not sure about img.onclick, but I suspect they could be related.